# Mock for several predicates

Tags: c#, mocking, moq

I create a mock object with one method

```
IMyIterface dosGuard = Mock.Of<IMyIterface >(
                dg =>
                dg.IsMethod1(It.IsAny<IPAddress>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()) == false
        );
```

I would like to specify the predicate for other method also :

```
dg.IsMethod2(It.IsAny<IPAddress>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>()) == false
```

How can I do it for both methods together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to setup multiple things on your mock object you can't* use the `Mock.Of<T>` factory method, you need to setup the mock object yourself:

```
var dosGuardMock = new Mock<IMyInterface>();
dosGuardMock.Setup(dg => dg.IsMethod1(It.IsAny<IPAddress>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
dosGuardMock.Setup(dg => dg.IsMethod2(It.IsAny<IPAddress>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
var dosGuard = dosGuardMock.Object;
```

*Alternatively, you *can* use the factory method, and use the static `Mock.Get` method to modify the instance created by the factory method:

```
var dosGuard = new Mock.Of<IMyInterface>();
Mock.Get(dosGuard).Setup(dg => dg.IsMethod1(It.IsAny<IPAddress>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
Mock.Get(dosGuard).Setup(dg => dg.IsMethod2(It.IsAny<IPAddress>(), It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(false);
```

However, I prefer the first example, because it draws an explicit difference between the `Mock<T>` instance and the "mock" `T` instance.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you actually can factory build the entire object's structure with `Mock.Of<T>()` -- it just appears a little quirky at first:

```
interface IInterface 
{
    int IntMethod();
    string StringMethod();
}
var instance = Mock.Of<IInterface>(ifc => 
                 ifc.IntMethod() == 1 &&
                 ifc.StringMethod() == "Hello");
```

It uses boolean as MemberAssignment, but aside from that, it would read get me a Mock of IInterface, with an IntMethod returning 1 and a StringMethod returning "Hello".  Also the `It.IsAny<TType>()` for parameters works in the predicate, as well as nested `Mock.Of<T>` calls.

Once you get going though, it becomes much cleaner, and one can spin up static methods for assignment/updating root test scenarios : i.e. take 'optimal' model and tweak a few fields, without having to re-type the entire model.